# select with a sub query

Tags: select, subquery

I have a table which contains summary totals by date by location for sales,qty,trans and bud_sales
Is it possible in 1 query to select data for the current date and the week to date and the month to date
location,trans_date,sales,qty,trans,budget,wkSales,wkQty,wktrans,wkBud,mtdSales,mtdQty,mtdtrans,mtdBud

tried with the following

```
SELECT
  stockhst.TRANS_DATE,
  stockhst.LOCATION,
  stockhst.SALE_QTY,
  stockhst.SALE_VALUE,
  stockhst.TAX_VALUE,
  stockhst.ecomm_value,
  stockhst.TRANS,
  stockhst.COST_VALUE,
  stockhst.BUD_SALES,
  location.NAME,
  (SELECT SUM(stockhst.SALE_VALUE) AS wkSales
   SUM(stockhst.qty) AS wkqty FROM stockhst 
  WHERE TRANS_DATE > CURDATE()-7 AND LOCATION=location GROUP BY location)
  FROM
  stockhst
  INNER JOIN location ON stockhst.LOCATION = location.LOCATION
  WHERE TRANS_DATE = CURDATE()
```

It errors, not sure what I am doing wrong.